# Concurrency with Firefox add-on script and content script

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

As I was writing a Firefox add-on using the [Add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/dev-guide/welcome.html), I noticed that the add-on code and the content script code block the execution of each other. Furthermore, the add-on code seems even to block the interaction with other Firefox windows (not just tabs).

**What is the concurrency/process model of Firefox add-ons?**

**Is it possible to run add-on code and content script code concurrently without cooperative multithreading (a la timers)?**

**How many times is the add-on code loaded? Once per window? Once per tab? Once?**

The [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/dev-guide/addon-development/web-content.html) states:

> The Mozilla platform is moving towards a model in which it uses
>   separate processes to display the UI, handle web content, and execute
>   add-ons. The main add-on code will run in the add-on process and will
>   not have direct access to any web content.

So I hope that in the future that they are indeed separate processes that will not interfere with each other, but that doesn't seem to be the case now.

---

**Update:**

I have tried using a page-worker from the add-on code, but unfortunately that still blocks the content script (as well as all other javascript). I also tried using a web worker in the page-worker, but I get the following error when calling the web worker's postMessage function.

> TypeError: worker.postMessage is not a function

I also tried creating an iframe in the page-worker and then creating a web worker in the iframe, but unfortunately I cannot use window.addEventListener from the page-worker. I get the following error:

> TypeError: window.addEventMessage is not a function

Finally, I tried to inject script (via script element) into the page-worker page to create a web worker which does seem to work. Unfortunately, I cannot communicate with this web worker because I can only send messages to it via document.defaultView.postMessage.

Oh the tangled webs I am weaving...

content-script -> add-on -> page-worker -> iframe -> web worker -> my code

---

I have included a simple example:

**package.json**

```js
{
    "name": "test", 
    "author": "me", 
    "version": "0.1", 
    "fullName": "My Test Extension", 
    "homepage": "http://example.com", 
    "id": "jid1-FmgBxScAABzB2g", 
    "description": "My test extension"
}
```

**lib/main.js**

```js
var data = require("self").data;
var pageMod = require("page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: ["http://*", "https://*"],
    contentScriptWhen: "start",
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("content.js")],
    onAttach: function (worker) {
        worker.port.on("message", function (data) {
            // simulate an expensive operation with a busy loop
            var start = new Date();
            while (new Date() - start < data.time);
            worker.port.emit("message", { text: 'done!' });
        });
    }
});
```

**data/content.js**

```js
self.port.on("message", function (response) {
    alert(response.text);
});

// call a very expensive operation in the add-on code
self.port.emit("message", { time: 10000 });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The messaging system has been designed with a multi-process environment in mind. However, this environment didn't emerge and it looks like it won't happen in near future either. So what you really have is both the add-on and the content script running in the same process on the main thread (UI thread). And that means that only one of them is running at a time, as you already noticed there is no concurrency.

> Is it possible to run add-on code and content script code concurrently without cooperative multithreading (a la timers)?

Yes, you [use web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers) (that have nothing to do with the `page-worker` module despite a similar name). This would be generally recommendable for expensive operations - you don't want your add-on to stop responding to messages while it is doing something. Unfortunately, the Add-on SDK doesn't expose web workers properly so I had to use the work-around suggested [here](http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla-labs-jetpack/tree/browse_frm/thread/91a88150aa7884ce/a9ce0639adaa9eee):

```js
worker.port.on("message", function (message) {
    // Get the worker class from a JavaScript module and unload it immediately
    var {Cu} = require("chrome");
    var {Worker} = Cu.import(data.url("dummy.jsm"));
    Cu.unload(data.url("dummy.jsm"));

    var webWorker = new Worker(data.url("expensiveOperation.js"));
    webWorker.addEventListener("message", function(event)
    {
      if (event.data == "done")
        worker.port.emit("message", { text: 'done!' });
    }, false);
});
```

The JavaScript module `data/dummy.jsm` only contains a single line:

```js
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS=["Worker"];
```

> How many times is the add-on code loaded? Once per window? Once per tab? Once?

If you are asking about add-on code: it is loaded only once and stays around as long as the add-on is active. As to content scripts, there is a separate instance for each document where the script is injected.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. If I try to create a web worker in the add-on code then it says _ReferenceError: Worker is not defined_. If I try to create a web worker in the content script then it says _ReferenceError: webWorker.addEventListener is not a function_.

Comment: @user967974: Yes, after looking through some Add-on SDK discussions, it looks like web workers aren't really supported yet. I updated my answer with a hack that allows you to use them nevertheless.

Comment: That seems to work, but there is one strange caveat. I cannot pass an object in postMessage to the worker. It throws the exception _The object could not be cloned_. Of course, I can serialize objects with JSON and then transfer the string to the worker. Thanks.

Comment: @user967974: `postMessage` only accepts JSON-serializable objects, this message appears whenever you try to feed it something that has no JSON representation. Then again, there might be scope issues (the JS module where you got `Worker` from had its own scope with its own `Object` and `Array` classes) and you indeed have to use JSON serialization manually.

Answer (score 0):

I found a hack to get WebWorkers in the extension's background page:

```
if(typeof(Worker) == 'undefined')
{
    var chromewin   =   win_util.getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    var Worker      =   chromewin.Worker;
}
var worker      =   new Worker(data.url('path/to/script.js'));
```

By accessing the main window's `window` object, you can pull the `Worker` class into the current scope. This gets around all the obnoxious `Page.Worker` workaround junk and seems to work fairly well.