# Concurrency and Multi-threading in Firefox Extensions

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing a Firefox extension using the Add-on builder and Add-on SDK. So far, I've been able to work around any limitations without moving to XUL. But, I've run into a roadblock.

My extension has a long running process, which may block, so I need to separate this processing from the main UI thread. I've read the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216984/concurrency-with-firefox-add-on-script-and-content-script), but it doesn't quite answer my question. Web Workers aren't sufficient since the long running process requires access to js-ctypes and native code. So, it would seem that [ChromeWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/ChromeWorker) might do the trick. But, I don't know how to get access to it from Add-on builder. Additionally, the Thread Manager is only accessible through C++ code. How can I either:

1. Access and instantiate Chrome Workers (or)
2. Create threads (or)
3. Fake concurrency (somehow)

to avoid blocking the UI thread. Alternatively, I could roll my own in native code (which I'm trying to avoid).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using chrome workers, they are meant specifically for using js-ctypes on a different thread. The thread manager has issues and using it from JavaScript has been disallowed for a reason. The main problem is however that `ChromeWorker` constructor isn't exposed in the Add-on SDK modules. But you can get it from the `chrome` pseudo-module:

```js
var self = require("sdk/self");
var {ChromeWorker} = require("chrome");
var worker = new ChromeWorker(self.data.url("worker.js"));
```

This works only starting with Firefox 8, in earlier versions you would [use the worker factory](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/Using_workers_in_JavaScript_code_modules). But I guess that you don't need that - new Add-on SDK versions don't support anything below Firefox 9 anyway.

*Note*: You should make sure to shut down this worker if your add-on is disabled or uninstalled (e.g. using [`unload` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/api-utils/docs/unload.html)), it won't happen automatically.

**Edit**:  Matthew Ruttley describes a simpler approach to import chrome workers in his [detailed blog post](http://ikigomu.com/?p=248), I updated this answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. How can I create a JavaScript module using the Addon builder? Is it possible to create one as part of the extension? Or, do I need to create a public Library to export the ChromeWorker? Thanks again!

Comment: @plin: See my code example... You don't need to create a module, there are plenty of them already available. You only need them to get the `ChromeWorker` constructor, after that you can just use it.

Comment: I tried creating a library and exporting the ChromeWorker. I was able to access it, but though instantiating new ChromeWorker created a worker, I was not able to post or receive any messages between my main script and the worker script.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it to work. I had some other statements in the worker.js that was causing it to fail silently. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ChromeWorker are now obsolete. Is there any alternatives to access js-ctypes/native code in another thread?

Comment: @antoyo: The "obsolete" note on MDN only refers to using XPCOM from ChromeWorker - this is no longer possible. ChromeWorker itself isn't obsolete however and using it to call js-ctypes on another thread is still supported.

Comment: Thanks. And is there a way to use XPCOM in a ChromeWorker or some other concurrent way?

Comment: @antoyo: No, this is no longer supported.

Comment: Ok, but is there any other way to use XPCOM in another thread? Or are we bound to fake concurrency?

Comment: @antoyo: No, XPCOM can only be called from the main thread. Performance-critical XPCOM calls have been made asynchronous anyway.