# js-ctypes with dll freezing browser

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

We use js-ctypes with own developed dll to get picture from image device in html page.
(timer-> get picture from device -> bmp 300kb base64 -> html )
Every 0.2 sec Addon calling image device  and every time addon working browser freezing at 0.5 sec. (intel i5, 16gb ddr)

I don't know how to use js-ctypes without freezing browser.
Make async response i think not cool with js-ctypes.
Maybe need using ports without waiting response from image device?

Comment: This guy here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478502/how-to-use-readdirectorychangesw-in-js-ctypes was trying to do async js ctypes too, definitely talk to him, i asked him in that topic how his work was going, hopefully he made some progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to use js-ctypes asynchronously is [ChromeWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChromeWorker). You have the global `ctypes` object there to use js-ctypes - and the execution runs on a separate thread so you don't have to worry about blocking the browser. If you need the data in the main thread later, you can send a message [like in a usual web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers).

*Note*: If you are using the Add-on SDK then you will notice that `ChromeWorker` isn't exposed in your modules. There is an [easy work-around for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511162/785541).

Comment: var worker = new ChromeWorker(data.url("async.js"));
and console say "ChromeWorker is not defined." Nightly 32.0.1
ChromeWorker  is not depricated?

Comment: @Alexufo: I guess that you are using the Add-on SDK and just forgot to mention that. See the note I added to my answer.