# TypeError: e.postMessage is not a function

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I'm trying to call window.postMesage from my java application for cross-origin communication with qlikview.

I am getting below mentioned java scrip error when I ma usinf latest Firefox 23 or 24

**TypeError: e.postMessage is not a function**

But same code work for Firefox version 10.
Can any one help? Let me know what i m missing. Is firefox has removed postMessage support or the api has been changed

Comment: What in the world is `e`?

Comment: This seems related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216984/concurrency-with-firefox-add-on-script-and-content-script I have a similar problem and am looking for a solution but this seems to complex.